# Tabbed page is not working properly after Xamarin.Firebase.Dynamic.Links installation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, firebase-dynamic-links

After the installation of Xamarin.Firebase.Dynamic.Links package, when I try to change the tabbed page current page from the navigation page, the blank page is shown.

Without this package my app works fine.

In iOS it is working fine. Only in android I am facing this issue.

I am using
Xamarin.Forms **5.0.0.2012**
Xamarin.Firebase.Dynamic.Links **120.1.1.3**

Comment: Can you show the code about **change the tabbed page current page from the navigation page**?